# form_for(@model) doesn't require instantiated @model—or does it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Originally I had a form_for(@thing) corresponding to the `create` action in my ThingsController. It worked. Then, I decided to move the form to its usual place, `/things/new.html.erb`, and the form stopped rendering. It gave this error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

So I added `@thing = Thing.new` to the `new` action, and all was well. But notice—I didn't have to instantiate `@thing` when the form was located elsewhere in another controller's view.

This leaves me wondering why Rails makes the seemingly arbitrary decision to require instantiation in one place and not the other. Anyone Rails-heads have an answer?

Comment: You might be calling the object somewhere in your new.html.erb. Post your code.

Comment: Right, it's being called in form_for(@thing). That's really all the code there is on the page, plus the form elements.

Comment: I've never been able to pass `form_for` a `nil` object. Maybe you're missing something?

Comment: Originally you masn't move your _form.html.erb file, it should lay in /app/tings/_form.html.erb and be rendered from new.html.erb file (or edit.html.erb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form_for(:thing)`. It will detect an instance variable names @thing yet still work if it is nil.

Comment: That's it! But with this, the form is POSTed to `/things/new` instead of `/things`, requiring the addition of `:url=> {:action=>"create",:controller=>"things"},`. I still prefer this way, as it is explicit and does not require the arbitrary instantiation of @thing.

Comment: Would you say this is worth opening a ticket about? It's not a bug but seems like inconsistent behavior.